# Convert minutes into a week to time using Java's Date and Calendar classes

Tags: java, datetime, time, calendar

#### Overview

This is the scenario: I'm given a value which represents a portion of the total number of minutes that exist in a standard week (assuming 10,080 minutes a week and 1,440 minutes a day) starting midnight Saturday (so 0 minutes Sunday @ 12am).

I need to convert this minute value into an actual time value (like 8:35am) and I want to use Java's Date and/or Calendar classes rather than calculate this by hand.

#### Example

Below are some example input values:

- 720 (720 minutes into the week) so 12pm on Sunday
- 3840 (3840 minutes into the week) so 4pm on Tuesday

Using Java's Date and Calendar classes how do I retrieve time component for that relative day?

Comment: Joda Time answer coming in 3... 2... 1...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also, with a Calendar is really easy:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
int minutesToAdd = 720;
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

cal.setTime(dateFormat.parse("2009/06/21 00:00:00"));  // Next sunday
cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, minutesToAdd);

Date result = cal.getTime();                           // Voila
```

Answer (score 1):

Divide by 24 hours in a day to get number of days.  Remainder is number of minutes into that day.

Divide by 60 to get hour.  Remainder is minutes into that hour.

Division and Modulus will get your answer in just a few lines of code.  Since this sounds like homework, I'll leave the coding out of this answer.

Answer (score 1):

As it sounds like homework, here how it should work:

```
1) Create yourself a calendar instance for sunday, 0:00 (on any date you wish)
2) Now add your minutes with the appropiate function
3) Now retrieve the time parts from the object
```

Comment: not homework :) just unfamiliar with the java calender classes and was having one of those brain farts...

Comment: no problem. thanks for taking the benefit of the doubt and answering the question regardless.

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate.now( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) )
         .with( TemporalAdjusters.previousOrSame( DayOfWeek.SUNDAY ) )
         .atStartOfDay( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) )
         .plus( Duration.ofMinutes( 720 ) )
```

## Using java.time

The modern way is with the java.time classes.

Which week? I will assume you want the Sunday of the current week.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z );
LocalDate sundayThisWeek = today.with( TemporalAdjusters.previousOrSame( DayOfWeek.SUNDAY ) );
```

Get the first moment of that date. Do not assume that means `00:00:00` as anomalies such as Daylight Saving Time (DST) may mean another time like `01:00:00`.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = sundayThisWeek.atStartOfDay( z ); // First moment of the day.
```

You say you are given an input of a number of minutes. Represent that as a `Duration` object.

```
Duration duration = Duration.ofMinutes( x );
```

Add the `Duration` object to your `ZonedDateTime` object.

> 720 (720 minutes into the week) so 12pm on Sunday

No, 720 minutes may result in some other time-of-day, such as 11 AM or 1 PM in the United States on the [DST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) cutover day.

The objects do all the math for you, and handle anomalies such as Daylight Saving Time.

```
ZonedDateTime zdtLater = zdt.plus( duration );
```

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).